# Keypress in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, keypress

Is it possible to detect keypresses without selecting anything on screen? I'm trying to make an online version of the Window's calculator. My searches so far have been fruitless; all I can find is how to detect keypresses in textboxes.

Comment: Why not set the focus to an input box and go from there?

Comment: There isn't a textbox, just buttons. So if I hit "9", it should be the same as pressing the button with a 9 on it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> My searches so far have been
>   fruitless; all I can find is how to
>   detect keypresses in textboxes

That's because in a web application that's the best you could do. You can intercept key presses only on elements that have the focus.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a javascript library to intercept the keypress in a browser.

Answer (score 0):

Set the focus on a hidden input element and catch the keypresses with javascript.